# Laptop backlight adjusts max brightness during boot

Tags: 20.04, brightness, backlight

I'm somewhat of a Ubuntu noob. I've been trying to fix this problem on and off for quite some time and figure I would just ask.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, everything was fine. My screen brightness was good, one day I adjusted it darker... perhaps I was in my room late at night. I'm just guessing I turned it off with it dark. I honestly have no recollection of the conditions when I shutdown the machine.

Ever since... that low level of brightness is the maximum brightness of my display. Using the brightness keys I can now bring my screen completely black. During boot up everything is initially fine, but at some mid-point the splash screen darkens.

The `xrandr -q; xrandr --output eDP-1-0 --brightness 2.0` brings the brightness to approximately the appropriate level but the contrast si off. I'm not sure what to do in the `/sys/class/backlight` directory... if anything. Nor am I sure about what to look for in the boot log. `journalctl -b` produces massive output.

The "perma-dim" is more of an issue for me than before due to a change in my work environment. Hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for the service that loads/saves the backlight setting I did not see the one referenced in my services. It loads/saves the backlight setting and apparently sometimes has issues doing so. What fixed the problem was executing:

`echo 100 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/<<press tab to get your device here>>/backlight`

`cat`-ing the `max_brightness` file in the same directory indicated a max of 255. The current setting was 12. The setting was retained after boot. Not the most technical answer but if it helps anyone (thumbs up).